# Is this PHP login technique safe considering SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I'am investigating a site that was written long ago by some PHP developer, and I'd like to know if the login technique he used was safe or not.

Here is the way he did it:

```
$username='';
$username = escapeshellcmd($HTTP_POST_VARS['user']);
$pwd = escapeshellcmd($HTTP_POST_VARS['pw']);

$loginerror=false;

if ($logout=="1")
{
  closesession($s_id);
  $username='';
  $logged=false;
}

$logged=checksession(session_id(), $ipaddr);

if ((!$logged) && ($username!=''))
{
        //$username = escapeshellcmd($HTTP_POST_VARS['felhasznalo']);
        //$pwd = escapeshellcmd($HTTP_POST_VARS['jelszo']);
        if (checkuser($username, $pwd, DOM))
            {
            if (sessionstore(session_id(), $username, $pwd, $ipaddr, $datum, DOM))
                {
                $logged=true;
                }
            }
        else
            {
            $loginerror=true;
            ;
            }       
}
if ($logged)
    {
    $username=getsessionuser(session_id());
    $remember=getremember($username, DOM);
    }
?>

function checkuser($u, $p, $d )
{
$sql_ell='SELECT PWD FROM USERS WHERE ACTIVE=1 AND USERNAME="'.$u.'" AND DOMAIN="'.$d.'"';
$eredm_ell= mysql_query($sql_ell);
if ($eredm_ell)
    {
    $domainnumrows=mysql_num_rows($eredm_ell);
    if ($domainnumrows==1) 
        {
        $egy_sor = mysql_fetch_row( $eredm_ell ); 
        $pwd_in_table=$egy_sor[0];
        if ($pwd_in_table==md5($u.$p))
            {
            return true;
            }
        } // rows
    } // ered
return false;   
} // func
```

Is this safe?

Comment: code review doesn't belong here. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would highly recommend reviewing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I see correctly, the only check done on username is `escapeshellcmd`. That is NOT enough. Again, if I see correctly, it gets put into this query:

```
$sql_ell='SELECT PWD FROM USERS WHERE ACTIVE=1 AND USERNAME="'.$u.'" AND DOMAIN="'.$d.'"'
```

where you can do all sorts of nasties.

**So no. it's not safe.**